# 5 meaningful contacts with Christians before considering the claims of the gospel

Tags: evangelism, non-christians, relationships, witnessing

I've been reading a book on Church growth (*Growing A Healthy Church* by Dan Spader and Gary Mayes) with a chapter on evangelism that says something which I've heard in churches before:

> "Typically a**n unbeliever needs to have more than five meaningful contacts** with a number of Christians before he or she will begin to trust the message of the gospel

[Growing a Healthy Church](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0802432301)

This seems to be a linchpin point supporting relationship-style evangelism but the book doesn't cite any sources and I don't seem to be able to find any myself. **Can someone else locate the source of this claim whether it be a study or merely an idea proposed by someone else?**

Comment: Glenn Daman refers to this in the book [Shepherding the Small Church](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=T6QhdZHePtMC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=five+meaningful+contacts+unbelievers&source=bl&ots=VGTg-6GXgy&sig=ACfU3U3fNNr3OkFt6z8J0bJn9A8I13kRdA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizmpriyLnrAhXSVsAKHXDECc0Q6AEwAnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=five%20meaningful%20contacts%20unbelievers&f=false). But this only refers to the link you give (which I have fixed). I can find nothing else to indicate it is not just an assertion.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, haven't been on this site for a bit so I'm a bit rusty

Comment: I have heard a similar claim by LDS, which I assume is unrelated to the book you mention. I didn't find a source though. I am adding this comment to say it is a notable claim that is not only held by Spader and Mayes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In marketing, this is referred to as the number of "touches" required to make a sale or convince someone. It is not unique to religion, nor does it guarantee success. In marketing, this is called "funneling":

[image]

In fact, this approach only works on a small subset (typically a one-digit percentage) of the number of contacts.

[The number of touches documented in market research is usually 6 to 8](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:W7eIDY0EW6EJ:https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/04/takes-6-8-touches-generate-viable-sales-lead-heres-why-gp.html%20&cd=14&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=be), which corresponds to  "**more than five** meaningful contacts" in the question posted.

Comment: Wow thanks for this. I asked someone in my denomination and he said there were some marketing studies to back the idea up but I couldn't track them down.

Comment: Very interesting expose of modern evangelical methods and their origins.